# USB webcam not found in Ubuntu guest OS

Tags: virtualbox, webcam

I have a Dell laptop shipped with Windows 10. I have Ubuntu guest OS on a virtual box. The webcam is visible within the host OS but not in the guest OS(Ubuntu). I have attached screenshot to illustrate the whole situation. Some comments in some forums suggested click F10(camera function), which is not available in my laptop. I installed Cheese and used it from the command line and were able to open the camera window with "device not found" error. How do I troubleshoot this problem?[image] 
[image]

As you can clearly see in the image above, the webcam is not available in the preferences page of Cheese console.

**UPDATE**: Based on @steeldriver's comment, if I select my webcam in Devices->USB I am getting "Failed to attach device" error like the screenshot shown below.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to pass the camera device to the VM.

Comment: ... specifically, for VirtualBox, go to the Devices menu then Select USB and choose your webcam device from the list

Comment: @steeldriver, I am getting "failed to attach USB" error when I do what you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out after hours of painful search and Google around the web. The issue lies in the Virtualbox extensions. 
First go to the [downloads page of virtualbox page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and download the extension that ***MATCHES YOUR VIRTUALBOX*** version, I highlighted this because it is very important that you do so. Download it in a known folder if your virtualbox is older but in the newer versions it installs in your virtualbox as soon as you click the extension file after it is downloaded. After that all you have to do is agree to the terms of service and it will be installed immediately. 
Last but not least is ***RESTART both the host and guest OS***, if you don't do this it will not work. That is it, now the webcam will be visible. Your virtualbox will also be able to support USB 2 and USB 3.